# "trends from 400M visitors" vs "trends by 400M visitors"

Tags: prepositions, writing-style

The Overflow Blog, April 20, 2020

> How the pandemic changed traffic trends **from** 400M visitors across 172 Stack Exchange sites.

I have a problem with one of the prepositions used in that statement, most noticeably "from". It feels that the sentence should end something like this: "traffic trends **from** 400M **to** 550M" Instead, the [announcement](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/04/20/pandemic-changed-traffic-trends-stack-exchange-sites/?cb=1) is about the change in visitors' interests and participation across the SE network. Biology.SE and Puzzle.SE, to name but two, owing to the recent pandemic have witnessed a significant surge in numbers of posts and visits.

My quibble is with "from", would "by" have been incorrect?

> How the pandemic changed traffic trends **by** 400M visitors across 172 Stack…

Chrome's online dictionary seems to confirm my impression: **by** “identifying the agent performing an action.”

Or would the following be clearer; stylistically better?

> How 400M visitors **from** 172 Stack Exchange sites changed traffic trends **during** the pandemic…

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a problem with [...] the preposition [...] "from"
>
> How the pandemic changed traffic trends **from** 400M visitors across 172 Stack Exchange sites.

I tend to agree with you. I had to read it twice to see what the author intended, and I too expected "to 500M...".

The preposition “**from**” is basically concerned with the locative origins of something:

I went **from** France to Italy. *My original location was France…*

I’m **from** France *My original location is France…*

It was made **from** gold mined in this valley. *The material used to make it was gold that originated in mines in this valley*

You can’t get blood **from** a stone *Blood cannot originate in a stone*

I caught the disease **from** a cow. *A cow was the origin of my disease*

The prepositional phrase in question modifies “traffic trends”

How the pandemic changed traffic trends from 400M visitors across 172 sites = How the pandemic changed traffic trends that originated in the 400M visitors across 172 sites(?) - This suggests that the **traffic trends** had their origins in 400M visitors whereas it is ***the change in* the traffic trends** that is the real subject and the pandemic that is the cause.

The immediate idiomatic alternatives are “**by**” which, as you point out is adverbially instrumental, and “**of**” which creates a contextual adjectival association.

How the pandemic changed traffic trends **by** 400M visitors across 172 sites = How the pandemic changed traffic trends by the use of 400M visitors across 172 sites– here there is an implied “an increased 400M visitors”

How the pandemic changed traffic trends **of** 400M visitors across 172 Stack – this implies that there are regularly 400M visitors (traffic) and they have trends and the trends have changed. I assume that this is what was meant.

Answer (score 0):

Users aren't the agent of traffic trends. They are simply too far removed from all the slicing and dicing analytics implied by *traffic trends*. *Traffic*, originally and still today, focuses on the commoditization of the transport process itself, not on the content being transported. And like the content, the source of the content is irrelevant.

*How the pandemic changed traffic trends* needs a full stop or a colon or em-dash, you can't hang a PP phrase with causal implications, because *traffic* doesn't work that way.

So I can't really make sense of either the original or your alternative.

How the pandemic changed traffic trends: an analysis culled from 400M visitors spanning 172 sites.

*Traffic* does accept geospacial PPs, as in traffic from Michigan, but not PPs which refer to the things trafficked.

Comment: I proposed two alternatives, and this post doesn't answer whether "from" is used correctly or not in the original announcement.

Comment: @Mari-LouA  I don't know how to be any clearer than to say no, you can't do that because *traffic* doesn't work that way. It's the original meta-data, and you can't address attributes of the content such as authorship because *traffic* doesn't admit to content. The only attribute *traffic* has is volume. "Traffic from/by users doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

This my interpretation where the words in bold are implied.

How the pandemic changed traffic trends from (**data generated by the**) 400M visitors across 172 Stack Exchange sites.